# Validating Security-Scoped Bookmark Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, sandbox

Asking Google about 'valid security-scoped bookmarks,' I don't get a good result.  Anyway, I don't have trouble saving and reading **security-scoped bookmarks**.  I have an **XML** file that saves an **NSMutableArray** that lists just one security-scoped bookmark for an export path the user has selected.  The application reads this bookmark with the following method.

```
- (void)loadBookmarks {
    if ([self fileExists:[self filePath1]]) { // function
        NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self filePath2]];
        key2a = @"KEY2a";
        for (NSInteger i5 = 0; i5 < items.count; i5++) {
            NSData *k1 = [[items objectAtIndex:i5] objectForKey:@"KEY2a"]; // bookmark

            // Start Security-scoped bookmark //
            NSURL *bookmarkFileURL;
            bookmarkFileURL = [self convertBookmarktoURL:k1]; // function
            [bookmarkFileURL startAccessingSecurityScopedResource]; // <<< no error
            // End Security-scoped bookmark //

            dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:k1,key2a,nil];
            [bookmarkArray1 addObject:dict2];
        } // End for
    }
}
```

If I try manipulating data in the XML file manually, the debugger doesn't indicate an error of any kind.  Is there any way of validating this data?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: App Sandbox Design Guide says "When you later need access to a bookmarked resource, resolve its security-scoped bookmark by calling the the URLByResolvingBookmarkData:options:relativeToURL:bookmarkDataIsStale:error: method of the NSURL class."

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I need to examine the error returned by **NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithSecurityScope**.

```
- (NSURL *)convertBookmarktoURL:(NSData *)bookmarkData {
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL bookmarkDataIsStale;
    if (error != NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:bookmarkData options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithSecurityScope relativeToURL:nil bookmarkDataIsStale:&bookmarkDataIsStale error:&error];
    }
}


// data is NSData
if ([self convertBookmarktoURL:data] != NULL) {
    // valid
} else {
    // invalid bookmark
}
```